# AWS Cognito- get user information with ID

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is there any way to get information about the user in AWS Cognito pool (on android) who is not logged in, knowing his ID? I tried that code:

```
 AppHelper.getPool().getUser(username).getDetailsInBackground(detailsHandler);
```

However it works only for username who is currently logged in.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not.

You get get user information given the user name by calling [AdminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) from you backend with your developer credentials but not from an Android client.

Comment: What in the situation when I logged in as an normal user and want to see another user profile (picture, etc). How to get those inforamtion about anther user?

Comment: Cognito user pools does not support that use case as of now.

Comment: I am building a social app on AWS. Then how can I make user-friends connections or display for example users who joined a certain event (with their profile pics?)? Is there any way to go over it with AWS?

Comment: I would like to know the same. Is the only way to build a proxy?

Comment: Hi chetan. Consider the case when the app needs to check if the userid exists or not to determine whether to show login or signup prompt. Here, we need to check if the userid exists. Any pointers on how to achieve this appreciated

Comment: I need this too. If I want to email the user inside lambda I need the users email.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListUsers()` Api , with filters ie

```
    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name=USER_POOL_REGION)
    user = client.list_users(
            UserPoolId = USER_POOL_ID,
            AttributesToGet=attributes, # ie ['email', 'sub',]
            Filter='sub = "<user-id-here>"',
            #Limit=limit
    )
```

for complex filters and examples see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/how-to-manage-user-accounts.html#cognito-user-pools-searching-for-users-listusers-api-examples