# AWS Cognito: get user attributes of any unauthenticated user

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to [get user attributes](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/7d40a3db071db03015625d8745e836d3a18e8d26/src/CognitoUser.js#L766) of any AWS Cognito user from a client which is unauthenticated or authenticated as another (non-admin) user?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944001/aws-cognito-get-user-information-with-id) post it is not possible. This seems like an awful limitation for user management as a service. Is the only viable solution to build a proxy service that will use [AdminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "authenticated as another (non-admin) user?"

Comment: I mean authenticating with Cognito as regular user of a pool with user specific credentials. This would be the typical usecase: authenticated users of a website are usually able to see other users profiles without needing elevated / admin privileges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this without compromising security currently. The chosen way would be a proxy service like you mentioned.